# Dropdown Filter for "services" in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, dropdown, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-filters

I want to create a filter dropdown for my project when I clicked on any services all the similar types of services a filterout.

**This is controller code**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    use App\Models\mprojectm;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\withPagination;
    use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
    use DB;
    
    
    
    class Mproject extends Component
    {
        use WithFileUploads;
        use withPagination;
        public $modalFormVisible = false;
        public $modalConfirmDeleteVisible = false; 
        public $modelId;
        public $title;
        public $industries;
        public $services;
        public $technologies;
        public $tags;
        public $description;
        public $rud;
        public $isd;
        public $usd; 
        public $clientname;
        public $clientlogo;
        public $pictures;
        public $demodetails;
        public $authorname;
        public $authorimage;
        public $feedback;
        public $searchTerm=null ;
    
    
        public function rules()
        {
            return[
                'title' => 'required',
                'services' => 'required',
                'technologies' => 'required',
            ];
        }
    
    
        public function export()
        {
            return Storage::disk('exports')->download('export.csv');
        }
    
        public function create()
        {
            // $this->pictures->store('pictures');
            // $this->validate([
            //     'clientlogo' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
            // ]);
            // $clientlogo=$this->clientlogo->store('clientlogo');
            $this->validate();
            mprojectm::create($this->modelData());
            $this->modalFormVisible = false;
            $this->resetVars();
        }
    
        public function update()
        {
            mprojectm::find($this->modelId)->update($this->modelData());
            $this->modalFormVisible = false;
    
        }
    
        public function delete()
        {
            mprojectm::destroy($this->modelId);
            $this->modalConfirmDeleteVisible = false;
            $this->resetpage();
        }
    
    
        public function read()  //Request $request
        {
            // $services =DB::table('mprojects')->select('services')->distinct()->get()->pluck('services');
            
            // $mprojectm = mprojectm::query();
    
            // if ($request->filled('services'))
            //  {
            //      $mprojectm->where('services',$request->services);
            //  }
            // else{
            //      return mprojectm::paginate(5);
            //  }
                    
            
             if($this->searchTerm!=""){
                    $data = mprojectm::query()
                    ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                    ->latest()->paginate(5);
                    return $data;
     
             }
             else{
                    return mprojectm::paginate(5);
             }
            
        }
    
    
        public function createShowModal()
        {
            $this->resetVars();
            $this->modalFormVisible = true;
            
        }
    
        public function updateShowModal($id)
        {
            $this->resetvars();
            $this->modelId = $id;
            $this->modalFormVisible = true;
            $this->loadModel();
    
        }
    
        public function deleteShowModal($id)
        {
            $this-> modelId = $id;
            $this-> modalConfirmDeleteVisible = true;
    
        }
    
        public function loadModel()
        {
            $data = mprojectm::find($this->modelId);
            $this->title = $data->title;
            $this->industries = $data->industries;
            $this->services = $data->services;
            $this->technologies = $data->technologies;
            $this->tags = $data->tags;
            $this->description = $data->description;
            $this->rud = $data->rud;
            $this->isd = $data->isd;
            $this->usd = $data->usd;
            $this->clientname = $data->clientname;
            $this->clientlogo = $data->clientlogo;
            $this->pictures = $data->pictures;
            $this->demodetails = $data->demodetails;
            $this->authorname = $data->authorname;
            $this->authorimage = $data->authorimage;
            $this->feedback = $data->feedback;
    
        }
    
    
        public function modelData()
        {
            return[
                'title' => $this->title,
                'industries' => $this->industries,
                'services' => $this->services,
                'technologies' => $this->technologies,
                'tags' => $this->tags,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'rud' => $this->rud,
                'isd' => $this->isd,
                'usd' => $this->usd,
                'clientname' => $this->clientname,
                'clientlogo' => $this->clientlogo,
                'pictures' => $this->pictures,
                'demodetails' => $this->demodetails,
                'authorname' => $this->authorname,
                'authorimage' => $this->authorimage,
                'feedback' => $this->feedback,
    
            ];
        }
    
        public function resetvars()
        {
            $this->modelId = null;
            $this->title = null;
            $this->industries = null;
            $this->services = null;
            $this->technologies = null;
            $this->tags = null;
            $this->description = null;
            $this->rud = null;
            $this->isd = null;
            $this->usd = null;
            $this->clientname = null;
            $this->clientlogo = null;
            $this->pictures = null;
            $this->demodetails = null;
            $this->authorname = null;
            $this->authorimage = null;
            $this->feedback = null;
            
            
        }
    
        public function mount()
        {
            $this->resetpage();
        }
    
        // For Dropdown filter
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $services =DB::table('mprojectm')->select('services')->distinct()->get()->pluck('services');
            
            $mprojectm = POST::query();
    
            if ($request->filled('services'))
                {
                    $mprojectm->where('services',$request->services);
                }
    
            return read();
        }
        // For Dropdown filter end
    
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.mproject',[
                'data' => $this->read(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**this is view code-**

```
         <div class="p-10">
                <div class="dropdown inline-block relative">
                    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
                        <span class="mr-1">Services</span>
                        <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/> </svg>
                    </button>
    
                    <!-- <select name="services" id="services" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
                        <option value=""> services</option>
                        @foreach(  $data as $item)
                            <option wire:click="index"> {{ $item->services }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select> -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 ">
                        @foreach($data as $item)
                            <li class=""><a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">{{ $item->services }}</a></li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <style>
                .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
                {
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: At least you need to add a question statement related to your effort. For example " I've tried to add a dropdown inside `<div>` but it doesn't work. Where should I place my dropdown?".

Comment: $mprojectm->where('services',$request->services)....must have ->get();